# Internationalization: Map and popuate error messages for single error code based on a pattern

Tags: internationalization, mapping, error-code

I have the following scenario to be designed for my application:

I will have error codes generated for exceptions/failures. I want to create an Error object(Default bean) as follows:

```
ErrorInfo
{
    String code;
    List<String> causes;
    List<String> remedies;
}
```

And my properties file will contain something like:

```
ERROR_NAME_CODE = 1001
ERROR_NAME_CAUSES_1 = First cause
ERROR_NAME_CAUSES_2 = Second cause
ERROR_NAME_REMEDIES_1 = First remedies{0}, test
ERROR_NAME_REMEDIES_2 = Second remedy
ERROR_NAME_REMEDIES_3= Third remedy
```

In the above case I have mapped all the related messages for error code 'ERROR_NAME' in the properties file.

Solution should be able to address the following requirements:

1. Mapping should be customizable. ErrorInfo class can be extended and add more attributes.
2. The pattern for grouping error messages based on error code should also be dynamic something like FilterCriteria be passed and invoke the custom implementations.
3. Error messages can be formatted using argument values.

I would like to understand if there is a standard design pattern or a framework that supports these requirements(may be customizable)

Thanks

Comment: Client will invoke the API by passing the error code and fully populated error info type should be returned back.